# Find Each Record in DB, Identify and Delete part of a String, then resave record to DB

Tags: ruby, string

My img records in my image model are currently saved with a version number:

```
_v1363823750/ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png
```

and I need to delete parts of them, so that they look like this:

```
ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png
```

What's the best/safest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below:

```
'_v1363823750/ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png'.split('/').last
 # => "ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png"
```

or

```
s = '_v1363823750/ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png'
s[s.index('/')+1..-1]
# => "ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png"
```

or (In this case the below would be the best way to go using [**File#basename**](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#basename-class_method))

```
File.basename('_v1363823750/ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png')
# => "ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png"
```

Comment: @BrianMcDonough I have given you the documentation link also. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one step with `sub`:

```
"_v1363823750/ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png".sub(%r{.*/}, "")
# => "ll9z2kvmtubfkugmtues.png"
```